# Need to know whether my project is web app project is maven or not

Tags: maven, web-services, web-applications, ant

I have a legacy web service project which structure seems to be maven project structure.

```
   src\main\java
   src\main\resources
   src\main\webapp
   src\main\test
   src\main\wsdl
```

It doesn't have any pom.xml file and built using Ant(build.xml is there) . I couldn't able import this file as Ant project  , so i created a dynamic web project and trying to paste the source files in appropriate position . so let me put my questions like

1. Is it possible to create a maven project and not to use pom.xml for managing dependencies ?
2. If its a maven project , there should be some artifact configuration in build.xml file but there is 
    none in my build.xml?

   and also please guide me how to structure this project(either should i create maven project or dynamic web project) in eclipse so that i can start working on it .

Comment: Looks like something originally created in Netbeans.  Perhaps try that first.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen . What shld i create .. dynamic web project ??

Comment: Are there any configuration files in the project?  If yes, which?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen There is no configuration file other than web.xml and build.xml .. Its actually a decade old soap web service  project i believe ..

Answer (score 1):

If there is no `pom.xml`, it is not Maven.

But probably it can be build with Maven if you write a `pom.xml` that lists all the relevant dependencies.